# After the program is run, the window generated by the program is blank and has no components

Tags: java, swing

I want to implement a GUI program that can write and read files, but the interface after my program runs is blank without any components. I use IDEA, and I have created the file in advance.The ultimate goal of this program is to design a text field and two buttons. When the "read file" button is clicked, the data information in the disk file will be displayed in the text field.

When the: Write File button is clicked, the user's input in the text field is written to the disk file.

[image]

This is the default interface for my program when it starts running. As you can see, it's just a small form control

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lu9cO.png)
This is the default interface for my program when it starts running. As you can see, it's just a small form control

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Ftest extends JFrame{
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;
    private JPanel jContentPane=null;
    private JTextArea jTextArea=null;
    private JButton openButton=null;
    private JButton closeButton=null;
    private JPanel controlPanel=null;

    private JTextArea getjTextArea(){
        if(jTextArea==null){
            jTextArea=new JTextArea();
        }
        return jTextArea;
    }
private JPanel getControlPanel(){
        if (controlPanel==null){
            FlowLayout flowLayout=new FlowLayout();
            flowLayout.setVgap(1);
            controlPanel=new JPanel();
            controlPanel.setLayout(flowLayout);
            controlPanel.add(getOpenButton(),null);
            controlPanel.add(getCloseButton(),null);
        }
        return controlPanel;
}
private JButton getOpenButton(){
        if(openButton==null){
            openButton=new JButton();
            openButton.setText("写入文件");
            openButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    File file=new File("D:\\tpg.txt");
                    try{
                        FileWriter out=new FileWriter(file);
                        String s=jTextArea.getText();
                        out.write(s);
                        out.close();
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        return openButton;
}
private JButton getCloseButton(){
        if(closeButton==null){
            closeButton=new JButton();
            closeButton.setText("读取文件");
            closeButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    File file=new File("D:\\tpg.txt");
                    try {

                            FileReader in=new FileReader(file);
                            char byt[]=new char[1024];
                            int len=in.read(byt);
                            jTextArea.setText(new String(byt,0,len));
                        in.close();
                    } catch (Exception e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        return closeButton;
}

public Ftest(){
        super();
        initialize();
}
private JPanel initialize(){
        if(jContentPane==null){
            jContentPane=new JPanel();
            jContentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            jContentPane.add(getScrollPane(),BorderLayout.CENTER);
            jContentPane.add(getControlPanel(),BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        }
        return jContentPane;
}

   public static void main(String[] args){
        Ftest thisClass=new Ftest();
        thisClass.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        thisClass.setVisible(true);
   }
   protected JScrollPane getScrollPane(){
        if(scrollPane==null){
            scrollPane=new JScrollPane();
            scrollPane.setViewportView(getjTextArea());
        }
        return scrollPane;
   }
}
```

Comment: This has *nothing* to do with Java EE.

Comment: I don't know what else might be wrong, but it seems you create a "content pane" in initialize() and return it, but you don't capture that return. You'll need to capture it and add it to the JFrame. Calling it "jContentPane" is also a little confusing, since that's a term Swing uses elsewhere.

Comment: I'm betting that @arcy has your problem in hand. You seem to be going about creating your GUI in a convoluted fashion and probably should simplify that code a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Swing components have a size of (0, 0). You need to give all your components a size by invoking the layout manager on all your panels. You do this by invoking the `pack()` method before the frame is made visible:

```
thisClass.pack();
thisClass.setVisible(true);
```